# How to remove the space between the minus sign and number's in informatica

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter, informatica-powerexchange

i have a issue  where the there is a amount field which has data like
 (-   98765.00),minus{spaces]{numbers}  ?, i need to remove the space between the minus and the number  and get is as (-98765.00), how  do i do it in expression transformation.

field datatype is decimal (8,2).

Thanks,
 Kiran

Comment: Hi All , i tried using reg_extract funciton but its returing null

Answer (score 0):

You can use `REG_REPLACE` function to replace space
To achieve this you need to follow below steps,
* Create two variable ports
* REG_REPLACE - function requires string column, so you need to convert the   decimal column to string column using **TO_CHAR** function
First variable port(string) - `TO_CHAR(column_name)`
* In previous port data is converted to string, now convert it again to decimal and apply **REG_REPLACE** function 
Second variable port(decimal) - `to_decimal(reg_replace(first_variable_port,'s+',''))`
s - determines the white spaces in informatica regular expression
See the below image,
[image]
same number which you provided is used. Use the same data type and function 
Debugger gives the exact result by removing white space in the below image,

[image]
May be you have the issue with other transformations which you are passing through. Debug and verify the data once.

Hope you got it, any issues feel free to ask
To have enjoy informatica, have a fun on https://etlinfromatica.wordpress.com/

Comment: The simpler REPLACECHR should also work in this case. Also, the column must be already coming as string, because you cannot have spaces in Number field.

Comment: If it is string, you can have reg_replace function straight away. replace_chr function is simpler, but using reg_replace is efficient and also fetches you a good knowledge on regular expressions

Comment: the field value is someting like this (- 553224.61), when i use the above logics its returing 0

Comment: Update answer with debugged image. Kindly verify

Answer (score 0):

```
output_port: TO_DECIMAL(REPLACECHR(FALSE,input_port,' ',''))
```

REPLACECHR replaces the blanks with empty character, essentially removing them. The first argument can be TRUE/FALSE to specify case sensitive or not, but it is not important in this case.

Comment: Hi ,I tried both the logics and non worked its returing '0'..:(

Comment: the field value is someting like this (-   553224.61), when i use the above logics its returing 0

Comment: You mean there are brackets and comma at the end?

Comment: no , but just  a multiple space's between( like 3 space tabs) the minus sign and the number. But some hwo the above logic;s are not working. input is decimal, and i converted to string ans used the above outpout_port logic with data type string

Comment: You have to read the data as string not decimal. Change the source definition to modify the data type. It is probably reading the value as 0 from source itself because of the spaces.

Comment: Also, you can run the mapping in debugger to check where it is getting converted to 0,from source or in the expression.

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct, you need to replace both the `spaces` and the `brackets`. Here's the expression:

```
TO_DECIMAL(
    REPLACECHR(0,
        REPLACECHR(0, '(- 98765.00)', ' ', '') -- this part does the space replacement
    , '()', '') -- this part replaces the brackets
)
```